# Check the value of the check box that changes every day with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I am checking the check box using `xpath` below.
Only the number after check changes.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//label[@for="check1"]').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//label[@for="check2"]').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//label[@for="check45"]').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//label[@for="check123"]').click()
```

The problem is that there are dozens of numbers and they change every day. I know the number that changes to an Excel file.
Putting the number in `openpyxl` was successful but I don't know how to put it in Selenium.
Can I put the number of Excel files I have in the command above automatically Or is my approach wrong?

Please give me some advice.

Comment: Can you provide the link to the web page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know what the numbers are ahead of time you can get them into a data structure like a `list` and then iterate over them

```
numbers = [1,2,3,4,5]
for num in numbers:
    elem = f"//label[@for='check{num}']"
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(elem).click()
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for your help but there's a problem. at the beginning check and the end {num}, the symbol is ". It's not ‘.  So I changed the symbol, and there's an error... Is there a way to express it differently?

Comment: the opposite should work just the same:  `elem = f'//label[@for="check{num}"]'`